# Linked list and object errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying my hand at JS and its assorted libraries and I'm running into an error I'm not quite sure how to interpret. The relevant code is as follows:

```
function plotPoint (y, next, prev) {
    this.y = y;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}

function Fourier() {
    var self = this;
    self.init() = function() {
        ...
        self.firstPoint = new plotPoint(250, null, null);
        console.log(self.firstPoint); [1]
        ...
    }

    self.animate() = function() {
        ...
        console.log(self.firstPoint); [2]
        self.updatePlot();
        ...
    }

    self.updatePlot = function() {

        console.log(self.firstPoint); [3]

        //add new point to beginning
        var newPoint = new plotPoint(self.leadPoint.y, self.firstPoint, null);
        self.firstPoint.prev = newPoint
        self.firstPoint = self.newPoint;

        //remove last point from list, leave for collection
        self.lastPoint = self.lastPoint.prev;
        self.lastPoint.next = null;
    }
}
```

All three of the console.log results show the correct object but the latter two are accompanied by an "undefined":

```
[1] plotPoint {y: 250, next: plotPoint, prev: null}
[2] plotPoint {y: 250, next: plotPoint, prev: null}
[3] plotPoint {y: 250, next: plotPoint, prev: null}
[2] undefined
[3] undefined
```

It then throws the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'prev' of undefined", referring to the line shortly after [3].

If it helps, the program was working when it wasn't wrapped up in the class Fourier. I was trying to modify it so I could use it with dat.GUI.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

EDIT: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/15gfcLwr/) to jsfiddle

Comment: A couple things bother me here...  self.init() = function() {..} doesn't seem legal.  self.init = function() {...} does.  Next, plotPoint does not return any value, so the value of newPoint here would be... null or undefined?  var newPoint = new plotPoint(self.leadPoint.y, self.firstPoint, null);

Comment: @wwwmarty: when function is invoked as a constructor (i.e., with a `new`), by default, it returns a new instance of itself - an object that taps into `plotPoint` prototype.  To @MrDiggles: how about creating a fiddle with your code sample: http://www.jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @DRD I added the link to the question

Comment: @MrDiggles It doesn't seem like your jsFiddle does anything when I click run (it just shows "PIXI.Container is not a function" in console). I'm using Chrome 45.

Comment: If you want to reach the method on your instance, you need to reference them `via this.init = init;` Also, you're using ES6 `let` declaration, make sure that you are under 'strict mode' or ES6 compatible.

Comment: A side comment.  If you are going to have several instances of `Fourier()`, then why not add all of its methods to its prototype?  Also, in this line `self.firstPoint = self.newPoint;`, the `self.newPoint` is never declared and hence it is `undefined` and that could be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object `self` does not have `newPoint`property, hence it is undefined.  When you assign `undefined` to `self.firstPoint` on line 106, then it becomes `undefined` also.

Comment: D'oh. Yeah that was the problem. Thanks for the help